# Fetch GPS location for every 5 minutes only

Tags: ios

In my Location Application implemented `didUpdateToLocation` method. This method called every second and provides location data. But I dont need to fetch location for every second, I need to fire this method every 5 minutes only. Is it possible to do this?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //initialize location lisetener on Application startup
    self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.myLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.myLocationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[INNOViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"INNOViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[INNOViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"INNOViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    /*
    if(self.executingInBackground)
    {
        NSLog(@"Aplication running in background");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Aplication NOT running in background");
    }
     */


    //NSLog(@"new location->%@ and old location -> %@",newLocation,oldLocation);

    NSString *urlAsString = @"http://www.apple.com";

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) {
            NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Downloaded html -> %@",html);
            //NSLog(@"Downloaded successfully");
        }
        else if([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Nothing downloaded");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error occured -> %@",error);
        }

    }];
}
```

Comment: If you really want to just get it every 5 minutes then you probably should use a timer. Start a timer with a 5 minute countdown, get the most accurate position, and then start it again and do this over and over again.

Comment: if initialize location manager object and start listening inside timer, then if Application go to background, the didUpdateToLocation event will fire or not?

Comment: Applications in the background are not active so this would not fire. Alternatively you can request the operating system to work in background mode, but you will be granted this for just a limited amount of time, unless your application is of a certain kind, such as a VOIP or Navigation app. Those have background priviledges.

Comment: You can use the significant changes update in the background, or the regular location updates (though apple rejects these a lot since idiots misuse them).  You will not be able to waste the user's battery by calling your own method every 5 minutes though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the accuraccy and the distance filter,this will reduce the frequency in which the method is called
If you want it to be called after 5 minutes then you can forcefully call the methods stopupdating  and startupdating every five minutes

Answer (score 3):

It is called that quickly because you asked for `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`.  Back off a bit.  It's not based on time, it's based on delta distance.  At that accuracy even a small change in distance will trigger an update in an area with good reception.  Use a different value.

Again, these methods are not meant to be used based on time.  They are meant to be used based on *delta distance*.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
[self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

use:

```
[self.myLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

If you use: `startUpdatingLocation` it'll call the delegate method in each second. When you use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` it'll call the delegate method when a significant change in location occurs or after 5 minute intervals.

---

> **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges**
>
> Starts the generation of updates based on significant location
>   changes.
>   `- (void)startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method initiates the delivery of location events asynchronously,
>   returning shortly after you call it. Location events are delivered to
>   your delegate’s locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method. The first
>   event to be delivered is usually the most recently cached location
>   event (if any) but may be a newer event in some circumstances.
>   Obtaining a current location fix may take several additional seconds,
>   so be sure to check the timestamps on the location events in your
>   delegate method.
>
> After returning a current location fix, the receiver generates update
>   events only when a significant change in the user’s location is
>   detected. For example, it might generate a new event when the device
>   becomes associated with a different cell tower. It does not rely on
>   the value in the distanceFilter property to generate events. Calling
>   this method several times in succession does not automatically result
>   in new events being generated. Calling
>   stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges in between, however, does
>   cause a new initial event to be sent the next time you call this
>   method.
>
> If you start this service and your application is subsequently
>   terminated, the system automatically relaunches the application into
>   the background if a new event arrives. In such a case, the options
>   dictionary passed to the locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method of
>   your application delegate contains the key
>   UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to indicate that your
>   application was launched because of a location event. Upon relaunch,
>   you must still configure a location manager object and call this
>   method to continue receiving location events. When you restart
>   location services, the current event is delivered to your delegate
>   immediately. In addition, the location property of your location
>   manager object is populated with the most recent location object even
>   before you start location services.
>
> In addition to your delegate object implementing the
>   locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method, it should also implement
>   the locationManager:didFailWithError: method to respond to potential
>   errors.
>
> **Note: Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500
>   meters or more from its previous notification. It should not expect
>   notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the
>   device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager
>   is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner.**
>
> Declared In CLLocationManager.h

Reference [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

Comment: "not expect notifications more frequently than once every five minutes" is not the same as "called every five minutes"

Comment: i need to fire the event for every 5 minutes ,even if I am in same location

Comment: @Ram Then I suggest you write your own method that gets called on a timer every 5 minutes.  Whenever your location changes, just store it somewhere and use it next time your method gets called.  Don't expect to be able to do this in the background though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` instead of `startUpdatingLocation`. You would be updated only when user moves around 500 meters from last position